# Unable to ssh with key into my Synology NAS

Tags: linux, ssh, synology

This question has already been asked so many times, but the solutions don't work for me.
I'm trying to ssh with a key from an Ubuntu system to my Synology NAS, but I'm still asked the user password because the private key is too open

I've created my keys in /opt/duplicati/config/.ssh id_rsa and id_rsa.pub
Then I have used ssh-copy-id to copy the public key to my NAS.
But when I try to ssh into my NAS I'm getting this

```
ssh -p '9922' -i /opt/duplicati/config/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 'user@192.168.1.1'
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/opt/duplicati/config/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/opt/duplicati/config/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": bad permissions
user@192.168.1.1's password:
```

It's strange that the issue is related to the private key, but it complains that the 0644 permission for the public key is too open.

Solution for this are to reduce the permission to both keys and the .ssh folder to either 0400 or 0600, but when I do that, it seems ssh can't read the file anymore and I get this error

```
Load key "/opt/duplicati/config/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": error in libcrypto
```

I have tried this already with root and with an admin user, but I can't make it work.
Is this because my keys are not in the usual home folder ~/.ssh/ ?
From another ubuntu system I was able to ssh into my NAS with the key stored in ~/.ssh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -p '9922' -i /opt/duplicati/config/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 'user@192.168.1.1'
```

Your actual issue is that you're using the wrong key file for the "-i" parameter. The file with the ".pub" extension contains the public portion of the key. The corresponding file without the ".pub" extension contains the private part of the key. When you run an ssh client to connect to a remote server, you have to provide the private key file to the ssh client, not the public key file.

You probably have a file named "/opt/duplicati/config/.ssh/id_rsa" without the ".pub" extension. This is the file that you should use when running ssh:

```
ssh -p '9922' -i /opt/duplicati/config/.ssh/id_rsa 'user@192.168.1.1'
                                                  ^--- no extension
```

You're getting an error about permissions because private key files contain sensitive information, so the `ssh` program requires private key files to have permissions preventing others from reading it. The public key file (the file with the ".pub" extension) don't contain sensitive information, so the tool that creates key files creates the public key file with less strict permissions.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was using the public key instead of the private one

Answer (score 0):

Here's a related openssl [GitHub issue](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/13443) and a serverfault [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/895896/sshd-does-not-allow-publickey-authentication-due-to-libcrypto-bug). In both situations, generating a new key seems to have worked. This could feasibly be caused by a compatibility or corruption issue.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead please quote the important part and provide the link as reference only.